# Цикл на построчную отправку сообщений после получения сообщения от пользователя

Tags: python, циклы, telegram, бот

Пытаюсь написать телеграм бот на питоне, с использованием библиотеки telebot. Но встал перед проблемой. Изначальной задумкой являлось то, что бот, после получения названия компании\департамента, будет отправлять построчно вопросы из интервью (которое подгружается с локальной папки), и отправлять следующий вопрос уже после получения ответа от человека, который общается с ботом.
На данном этапе не получается реализовать отправку вопросов после сообщений пользователя. Вот кусок кода, который отправляет эти вопросы сразу, как бы не дожидаясь ответа пользователя. Как можно модифицировать цикл while, или чем его можно заменить? Концептуально, или кодом. Буду рад помощи и советам :_)

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_user_text(message):
    final_message = ""
    get_message_bot = message.text.strip().lower()
    if get_message_bot == "сбер":
        f = open('sber_interview.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8')
        while True:
            line = f.readline()
            mess = line
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess, parse_mode='html')
            if not line:
                break
        f.close
    elif get_message_bot == 'ростелеком':
        mess = f'Здесь будет первый вопрос из интервью Ростелекома, когда я настрою выгрузку'
```

Comment: Не попробовали FSM?

Comment: @СергейШашко посмотрел сейчас, впервые сталкиваюсь, ибо, по сути, вне базовых курсов питона это первая программа, которую я пишу. Не переусложнит ли это код? Или это простенькое решение в моей ситуации?

Comment: Не взависимости от моего ответа я бы хотя бы почупал, если это была моя первая программка хуже точно не будет. :)

Comment: Update: цикл while вынес вне тела if, и теперь имею список с вопросами, но отправляет бот все так же без ожидания ответа от пользователя. Если найдете хороший урок по FSM или есть другие методы решить проблему в данной ситуации - эта помощь все еще будет актуальна

Comment: все написанные сообщенния пользователями телеграмма проходят через @bot.message_handler()(что то типа пост обработка). Наглядный пример эхо-бот.

Comment: FSM для telebot https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py